# Is there a goodness of fit metric that can be computed online with $O(1)$ memory?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, online-algorithms

Say I have two random streams of two dimensional data. I want to measure how closely their underlying PDF's match. My current method is to estimate the PDF's by accumulating the samples online in a 256x256 histogram. After this, I measure the deviation between the two. I am using sum of absolute differences here, but I believe other metrics will work fine as well.

*Some other possibly relevant details:* I will be ranking the streams based on their goodness of fit; I don't actually need to perform any hypothesis testing— just find which has highest rank. Also, the distributions are complex, and I don't believe they can be estimated to sufficient accuracy by any well-known analytic distributions.

The problem is, the memory accesses on $t*2^{16}$ bins with $t$ threads, is a significant bottleneck. I was wondering if there were a way to compute the goodness of fit metric without having to accumulate $O(k)$ data about the distributions. Maybe something similar to how there are online calculations of mean/variance that just accumulate one or two variables along the way.

I have looked at Komogorov-Smirnov, Cramer-von Mises, and Shapiro-Wilk tests. They appear to require either 1) an estimation of the sample's CDF, which would still need $O(k)$ variables or 2) ordered data, which isn't possible with an unordered, random stream of data.

Maybe there's some fundamental limitation that prevents a computation comparing PDF's with just $O(1)$ variables?

Comment: 1. If your pmf is really discrete why do you need to accumulate a histogram on the first pass? Its not clear what you're doing there. The KS statistic is based on a difference in cdf, so the question is whether there's a fast update on that. If the pmf is only on a few atoms of probability it may be pretty fast to update. 2. Given a discrete pmf, the C-vM won't require sorting the observations; it should be possible to calculate it from the same cdf you'd update in a K-S, so again the question is whether the cdf is fast to update.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the test, but seems you need to first compute the empirical distribution function of the samples. For discrete data, you can calculate that efficiently from a histogram.

Comment: 3. If you're just computing a measure of fit with the S-W (not testing), you don't need to assume normality -- if you have some location-scale family you replace the calculation of expected order statistics. However, I am curious how you're doing it online (since a typical implementation would require something equivalent to sorting the data; however this could be gotten around with a discrete distribution). A chi-square statistic should be very fast to update but would be less sensitive than some other options.

Comment: You just said in your post that a histogram was too inefficient; it can't be both efficient and inefficient. If it is actually efficient, do it. If it is not, stop insisting on doing it that way and instead try to consider if there's a faster way to do it online. It looks to me like the crucial issue is how many values your discrete r.v. can take. If it's say 5 or 6 different values, no problem. If it's thousands, it will be slow to update an unnormalized cdf online.

Comment: Note that if you intend testing any of this you have multiple issues to contend with (such as the impact of the discrete distribution on statistics designed for continuous variables, the sequential testing)

Comment: I meant if you have a histogram already you can calculate its cdf efficiently. The problem would be building the histogram in the first place. I'm assuming updating a cdf or chi-square statistic would be about the same, since you're still accumulating the samples into $O(n)$ bins.

Comment: No, it's not O(n) bins. conventionally n is the number of observations, but you'll need a different symbol (say $k$) to represent the number of possible values taken by the discrete variable, and it's easy to update the counts. You'd still need an O(k) update in general (though in some special cases there's a few tricks that might speed things up; a uniform distribution might be faster than O(k) for example). If k is small, several of these statistics should be fast.

Comment: The purpose is just to rank the measure of fit for many candidate distributions; don't need to do hypothesis testing since I'm just interested in highest rank. You're right with SW, it does need ordered-- I misread that, haven't implemented anything yet. I'm estimating the candidate PDF's with PMF's, at least for now, but if there is a 2-sample test that is fast I will switch to that.

Comment: Wait, you're actually interested in comparing two samples? why are we solving the wrong problem?

Comment: Yeah, problem with stackexchange is they want a "minimal working example" so to speak, else the question gets too complex and nobody answers. So it is hard to pick which details to exclude. I figured if you can do it with a single sample, I can figure out how the 2 sample works myself

Comment: I know it is easy to update $k$ bins online, and normally it would be pretty fast too. For me the distributions are 2d (another detail I figure should be straightforward to generalize from 1d case), meaning 256*256 bins; then imagine 16+ cores contending for RAM access to accumulate histograms... it becomes a bottleneck. GPU texture memory might be a little faster, but I don't expect by much. So mostly wondering if there were some computation, like you would with online mean/variance calculation, where you could compute goodness of fit without accumulating $O(k)$ bins. Make any more sense?

Comment: If you have $k=2^{16}$ positions in the pmf that's worth mentioning in the post. What distributions are you looking at?

Comment: Updated the question with the answers to your comment inquiries. The distributions are complicated, which is why I was estimating as discrete PMF's.

Comment: How are you getting the discrete pmfs?

Comment: I'm discretizing the PDF as a histogram. Wouldn't that be equivalent to discrete PMF? You seem to have a good skill for poking holes in my understanding of statistics.

Comment: It is, but I was trying to get into what exactly that saved you. However, considering that the underlying problem is 2D you may want to avoid the issues with trying to get an order on observations in 2D anyway, so the chi-square may well be reasonably sensible and you'd be binning in any case. It sounds like the alternatives will tend to be smooth deviations though so there might perhaps be some power gain in looking at partitioning the chi-square and pulling off lower order components along the line of a Smooth test; that would complicate the updates though; I don't know how much.

Answer (score 2):

Consider updating a chi-squared statistic.

$X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(O_i-np_i)^2}{np_i}$

First let us simplify:

$= \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{O_i^2-2np_iO_i+(np_i)^2}{np_i}$

$= \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{O_i^2}{np_i}-2\sum_{i=1}^k O_i+n\sum_{i=1}^k p_i$

$= \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{O_i^2}{np_i}\,-n$

$= [\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{O_i^2}{p_i}]\,-n$

$= S/n - n$

If we can update $S=\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{O_i^2}{p_i}$ quickly it looks like there's a fast algorithm.

So now let us focus on updating $ S$

Note that $O_i$ is just the count in the $i$th bin. When you add a new observation to bin $i$, you add $(2O_i+1)/p_i$ to the sum - all the contributions from other bins are unchanged, and then you can recompute $S/n-n$ at the new value of $n$, this is $O(1)$ in both $n$ and $k$.

*Stability*

This may potentially be an issue; as $n$ grows you're subtracting two relatively equal quantities (the expected value of the first term $S/n$ should be about $n+k$(*) if the null is true but will tend to be larger otherwise). As $n$ grows very large relative to $k$ this may become an issue; specifically, computing something akin to $(1+k/n) - 1$ may be inaccurate if $k/n$ is very small.

At the same time if $n$ is really large, $S$ may be large relative to the increment in $S$. Ideally we avoid both issues by adjusting the S-calculation.

I believe the same sort of idea used in online variance update calculations could be adapted to this computation in that case, it would slightly complicate the update of $S$ - in a way that it's already reduced by $n^2$ (or something close to it).

Actually I think we just add something like $(2O_i+1)/p_i - 2n-1$ to $S$ instead and don't subtract $n$ at the final step (or it may be $-2n+1$ depending on when we update $n$).

(However if $n$ is only a few million it's probably not worth it; if you have several figures of accuracy on your statistic - and you should have plenty to spare - it will probably be sufficient to your purposes. If $n$ is many billions, you should do it but you will want to consider efficiency of the update pretty carefully then)

* actually, n+k-1 but that matters not in the least to the issue.

Comment: So maybe this is my fault for not clarifying precisely, and I apologize. I meant an online algorithm in that it reads the data one-by-one in a single pass. I don't actually need to compute the final metric on each iteration. In my original attempt, I'd accumulate $O(k)$ bins in a single pass, then compute the metric. The binning being the bottleneck, I was wondering if you could do it with just $O(1)$ memory total, over all iterations.

Comment: My line of thinking was something like: Assume $p_i$ is already known (accumulated before for one of the data streams). For each observation you see increment your metric by $p_i/n$, where $p_i$ is the observation's corresponding bin. That gives you $\sum p_io_i$, where $o_i$ is probability from 2nd data stream's bin... so maybe you could compare this to $\sum p_i^2$?

Comment: If your $p_i$ are themselves estimates of true p's based on data, the entire question is incorrectly specified and you should write a new one that explains that you want to compare proportions across data streams (or whatever it is you want). But if you have $p$s prespecified (as the question here suggests) then I don't see what you're getting at with this at all. In any case I don't see what you mean by "increment your metric" (what metric?) nor "where $p_i$ is the observations corresponding bin" (no, $p$ is a probability, $i$ is the bin, $n$ is the index of the current observation).

Comment: If you're trying to do it without storing either the $p_i$s or the $O_i$s that's going to be tricky. If you do store $p$, storing $O$ doesn't change the big-$\mathcal{O}$ factor on storage space, just the multiplier out the front. Anyway, I am presently confused (and I presumably missed something important), but maybe you can clarify.

Comment: I was coming from the angle, "if its impossible to compute in $O(1)$ when one of the distributions is known (e.g. $p_i$ known apriori), then its probably impossible when both are unknown." So it was just an intuition pump that got me thinking it might actually be possible. To clarify you've got $o_i$=1st distribution's histogram probabilities, $p_i$=2nd distribution's histogram probabilities (assume you estimated it already— actually unknown in real problem). Then if you make $N$ observations, you can compute $S=\sum_{n}^{N}p_i/N$, where $i$ is sample $n$'s bin. Giving you $S=\sum_i p_io_i$.

Comment: The formula doesn't actually work, which is why its just a thought. It would be an underestimate, since it only gives you the middle term in $(p_i-o_i)^2 = p_i^2-2p_io_i+o_i^2$. Would need to figure out how to calculate $o_i^2$ online in $O(1)$ for it to work. Then again, its all assuming $p_i$ is known, so not practical anyways.

Comment: Again, if this is "compare two sample distributions", you need a new question. Again, I don't quite follow what you're trying to achieve here, though defining that o was probabilities helps. Note that my O's are *counts* and if you wanted to compare two distributions it would be two sets of counts you'd work with.

Comment: Okay, I will try to write a new question then